# how to list the object in angular calling the java api with header and body?

Tags: java, angular, api, frontend, angular8

I want to list the student details calling the java api which have below response. I want the values from data which will have multiple values.Below is the method i am calling in component.ts class.

````
ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true
        this.httpService.get('/student').subscribe(
            result => {
                console.log('received results');
                this.loading = false;
                this.scouts = result;
            },
            error => {
                console.log('failed');
                this.loading = false;
            }

``
This is the api response. 
``
{
data: [
{
id: 101,
name: "John doe",
status: "enrolled",
}
],
errors: [ ],
warnings: [ ],
meta: { }
}
```

I tried to using this as html code but this won't work and in the component part i have called the httpservice with get request in ngOnInit part. 
``
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
        <td>{{student.id}}</td>
        <td>{{student.name}}</td>
        <td>{{student.status}}</td>
        ```

Please can you guide me how can i get the student details from data part and list it in front end. Thank you.
````

Answer (score 1):

From Best practices:

Use url at the service level (since it's a constant used only inside the service)

Define a `StudentResponce` model so that you can your json response.

Define the `Student` model that will be a property of `StudentReponse`

then your component becomes

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.httpService.getStudents().subscribe(
        result => {
            console.log('received results');
            this.loading = false;
            this.scouts = result.data;
            /*or this.scouts = [...result.data] */
            //warning = result.warning
            //meta = result.meta
            //errors = [...result.errors]
        },
        error => {
            console.log('failed');
            this.message = error.message;
            this.loading = false;
        });
  }
```

and the service

```
 const url = "http://replace_with_service_url";
 @Injectable()
 export class MyHttpService {

   constructor(private client: HttpClient) { 
   }
     getStudents(): Observable<StudentResponse>{
       return this.client.get<StudentResponse>(url);
     }
 }
 export class StudentResponse{
   data: Student[];
   warning: any;
   errors: any[];
   meta: any;
 }
 export class Student{
   id: number;
   name= "";
   status: string /*or enum "enrolled"*/;
 }
```

you can replace your service url in [this code](https://angular-mm8znn.stackblitz.io) to test

Answer (score 0):

Just change this assignment:

```
this.scouts = result;
```

to

```
this.scouts = result.data;
```

Comment: yes this will work but it thows error as Property 'data' does not exist on type 'unknown'.